# solving $ x = \frac{a}{a+b} $ for a

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been struggling with this for a while now. As you may understand my algebra is not so good at the time. I need this for my electronics project (not school)

The problem is this
$$
x = \frac{a}{a+b}
$$
How do I solve for $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=\frac{a}{a+b}$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$(a+b)x=a$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$ax+bx=a$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$ax-a=-bx$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$a(x-1)=-bx$$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$a=\frac{bx}{1-x}$$
Note you have to handle the case $x=1$ separately.  In that case $b=0$ and $a$ can be anything.

Comment: From fourth step is wrong , it should be $ax-a=-bx$

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Thank you, long day, brain half working...

Comment: Don't worry, Happens a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $x \neq 1$ 
$$
x=\frac{a}{a+b} \Leftrightarrow (a+b)x=a \Leftrightarrow ax+bx-a=0\Leftrightarrow a(x-1)=-bx \Leftrightarrow a=\frac{bx}{1-x} 
$$
If $x=1$ then $b=0$ and $a\neq 0$, because $1=a/a$, for any $a \neq 0$.

Comment: You still have to handle the case $x=1$ as a special case.

Comment: Done it !! thanks